# OPENPYXL: How can I get the maximum number of columns with data in a specific row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have my data in an excel file and I want to python to get the number of occupied cells in a specific row. How can I do that?

For instance, if I want to know how many columns are occupied with data in row 5, how would I achieve that?

PS: The cells are occupied with strings [Notice how some rows have more data than some (click here to see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wco8V.png)

Comment: This question has been asked a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate on the row:

```py
def get_filled_cols(row_obj):
    counter = 0
    for c in row_obj:
        if c.value != None:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

now you can check for row, 5 for example:

```py
get_filled_cols(ws[5])
```